# Unwanted horizontal lines at bottom of UITableView that uses a footer

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, footer

I have a UITableView initialised with UITableViewStyleGrouped. It contains a single group and a footer. I am experiencing unwanted horizontal lines repeated in front of the footer for the height of the footer. If I set the footer to hidden, the lines (and the footer) disapear. In the following example the footer height is set to 144px. I have seen examples of this problem where setting a transparent footer fixes the problem, however I cannot use this hack as I need a footer.

Here are two examples. Both use a single section and a footer:

[image]

[image]

The footer is very simple:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Footer
    UIView *footer = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    [footer.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]]; //Has no effect
    [footer.layer setBorderWidth:0]; //Has no effect
    //[footer.layer setHidden:YES]; //Hides entire footer and lines
    footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIButton *button = [ComponentFactory makeForgottenPasswordButton];
    [footer addSubview:button];
    return footer;
}
```

And I have tried hiding separators on the table view:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //Has no effect
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone; //Has no effect
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Sections and Rows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  // Return the number of sections.
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2;
}
```

Where are they coming from and how can I hide them?

Comment: Once question i would like to ask, why are using tableview for the login purpose?

Comment: Its quite common amongst iPhone apps. eg Soundcloud

Comment: It would be simple & easy to use labels and textfield.

Comment: Yes it would, however I am using a table.

Comment: If you dont want to display horizontal line,Goto to xib->select table change settings for tableview, seperator to "none"

Comment: I am not using a xib and if you read the question you will see I am already setting the separator style: tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

Comment: [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]; Put this code in method  heightForRowAtIndex

Comment: This has no effect as I have already set it to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone.

Comment: Any chance you solved this in the last 5 months?  I've got the exact same problem.

Comment: Having the same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I would check two things:

1) What is background color of your tableView?

2) How many sections are you providing via the data source?

With regards to (1), the default background for grouped-style UITableView is the background you are seeing. As an example of this, load up the Contacts app on your iPhone and select a contact. You will see various sections broken up all on top of the background you showed above. If you want some other color, provide a UIColor or some other color to the tableView's .backgroundColor property.

**UPDATE:** It also looks like the reason you have the "cell separators" is actually because you are not providing the correct cell height, so your text is basically bleeding over into the next cell. Try setting the cell height to something like 75.0 and see if that solves your problem. 75 is probably way too big, but it should get the point across.

Comment: Thanks. Have updated my question to clarify. If tableView.backgroundColor is set to [UIColor clearColor] I lose the stripes but keep the unwanted horizontal lines, and my delegate is returning 1 for the number of sections.

Comment: Thanks, but makes no difference.

Comment: Are you setting the height in the data source method - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath?